# Pandas Group by and then find mean not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following table:

```
quarter     town    flat_type   median_rent
2011    CLEMENTI    4-RM    2250
2011    CLEMENTI    4-RM    2300
2011    CLEMENTI    4-RM    2300
2011    CLEMENTI    4-RM    2400
```

The median average rent for 4-RM in 2011 is (2250+2300+2300+2400)/4 = 2312.5.

My current code:

```
test = df.groupby(["town","quarter"], as_index=True)


print(test['median_rent'].mean())
```

output:

```
town      quarter
CLEMENTI  2011       5.625575e+14
          2012       5.875638e+14
          2013       6.500675e+14
          2014       6.875675e+14
          2015       6.625650e+14
          2016       6.500650e+14
          2017       6.250613e+14
          2018       5.750575e+14
          2019       7.667467e+10
          2020       4.800470e+18
          2021       6.000625e+14
Name: median_rent, dtype: float64
```

This is not what is expeced. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the sample code that you have written, you actually need to group by *flat_type* and *quarter*, not *town* and *quarter*. Just try

```
test = df.groupby(["flat_type", "quarter"], as_index=True)
```

and see whether it is what you were expecting.

Edit: also, it is a great idea to share what you WERE expecting, because otherwise we have no way of knowing what do you want us to help with. This specific line of code does exactly what it is expected to do - groups by 2 attributes and takes an average of the 3rd attribute.

Answer (score 0):

the groupby object should be used either to split the groupBy key and grouped df, or to apply actions directly to

example of applying mean directly to the groupby

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv')
print(df)

test = df.groupby(["town","quarter"], as_index=True)['median_rent'].mean()
print(test)
```

tmp.csv

```
quarter,town,flat_type,median_rent
2011,CLEMENTI,4-RM,2250
2011,CLEMENTI,4-RM,2300
2011,CLEMENTI,4-RM,2300
2011,CLEMENTI,4-RM,2400
2012,CLEMENT,4-RM,2250
2012,CLEMENT,4-RM,2300
2011,CLEMENT,4-RM,2300
2011,CLEMENT,4-RM,2400
```

output

```
   quarter      town flat_type  median_rent
0     2011  CLEMENTI      4-RM         2250
1     2011  CLEMENTI      4-RM         2300
2     2011  CLEMENTI      4-RM         2300
3     2011  CLEMENTI      4-RM         2400
4     2012   CLEMENT      4-RM         2250
5     2012   CLEMENT      4-RM         2300
6     2011   CLEMENT      4-RM         2300
7     2011   CLEMENT      4-RM         2400
town      quarter
CLEMENT   2011       2350.0
          2012       2275.0
CLEMENTI  2011       2312.5
Name: median_rent, dtype: float64
```